# Droid 2 not detected by CSS @media query

Tags: android, css, browser, mobile, media-queries

I'm using the following CSS @media query to style my page for mobile browsers like iPhone's and Android's:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
     // CSS here
}
```

However, one of my users is saying that it's not detecting his Droid 2 phone. His user-agent string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; DROID2 GLOBAL Build/S273) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.12011-07-18 05:34:59
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Droid 2's screen is apparently 854x480, so try (max-device-width: 854px).

ref: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/reviews/2010/08/hands-on-motorolas-droid-sequel-is-a-worthy-update.ars

Comment: So is the Droid, DroidX, etc... also the 480 would be in portrait mode and the 854 would be in landscape. Anyway, even if they weren't they would be 800px wide/tall

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can do `(max-device-width: 480px) or (max-device-width: 854px)`?

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries: "you can combine multiple media queries in a comma-separated list; if any of the media queries in the list is true, the associated style sheet is applied.  This is the equivalent of a logical "or" operation." So it sounds like you want @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), (max-device-width: 854px)

Comment: probably it should be `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 854px)`, i.e. repeat the *only screen* part

Answer (score 0):

If you do `max-device-width: 854px` it will always include `480px`.
Key word: **Max**